# How to write test case for the extra functionality added after mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, flexmock

```
from flexmock import flexmock
class Addition:
    def add(self,num1,num2):
        return num1+num2
```

## creating a mock

```
mock=Addition()
flexmock(mock)

mock.should_receive('add')

assert mock.add(1,2)==3
```

I have mocked the Addition class using flexmock. Now Suppose If I further want to make sure that add method only receive integer value. How do I write the test case for added requirement. Or am I following the totally wrong path ?

Answer (score 0):

Well it really depends right. You could change your original function to have an `Exception` and you can test for cases that cause that to arise or you could do something like this (I use `pytest` btw):

```
def test_add(num1, num2):
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        return num1 + num2

test_add(2, 'fizz') ---> PASSED

test_add(2, 2) ---> FAILED
Failed: DID NOT RAISE <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
```

Comment: I want to do it in a mock way and confused how does it Go

Comment: Sorry I don't know, I prefer `pytest` it is much easier to understand imo.

Comment: how do you test API calls ,